# How to add password to website using Ngrok

Tags: ngrok

I'm using ngrok to expose my website to Internet, and I have a question is it possible using ngrok to add password to website, so before someone see the website has to enter password ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use basic ngrok authentication using bellow command to start exposing your server

```
ngrok http {port_which_you_want_to_expose} -auth="{username}: 
{password}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
ngrok http 8000 --basic-auth 'ngrok:issecure' --basic-auth="username:password"
```

You need the issecure flag, and also the `--basic-auth=` should be wrote like this not like `-auth=` only